# Construction of surfaces with Kodaira dimension 1

Tags: algebraic-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I am trying to find examples of surfaces with Kodaira dimension 1, but find it difficult to get. Can somebody help me come up with examples?

Thanks.

Comment: There are several examples on the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_surface

Answer (score 4):

Let $C$ elliptic curve and $C'$ a  (smooth projective) curve of genus $g \geq 2$, then $C \times C'$ has Kodaira dimension 1.